# Expiring Concurrent Dictionary

Tags: c#

Hi I'm doing some research after a concurrent dictionary with expiration features.

We have a list of objects that are accessed with adds and removes from a lot different threads.
We also want an expiration time on the items for like lets say 60 secconds.
(It would be nice if we can listen on an event that tells us which items that has been expired and removed from the list).

We also need the lookup to be really fast like an Dictionary.

The list will contain houndred of thousands objects.

So its like an ConcurrentDictionary but with expiration features.

Can MemoryCache be something?

Or are they other things to look on?

Comment: Have you considered simply using the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class? (edit) No, `MemoryCache` is exactly what you need, I didn't read your question thoroughly.

Comment: @Groo: OP asks about MemoryCache which is effectively the same as Cache without the dependency on System.Web.dll

Comment: @spender: oh, right, I just read the beginning of the answer and presumed OP want's to code it from scratch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) looks ideal, especially as

> This type is thread safe.

Comment: +1. It also [supports expiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.absoluteexpiration.aspx) [with notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.updatecallback.aspx).

Comment: The question is, are it really fast to add and remove?

Comment: @NPehrsson I think you'll have to test that yourself.

Comment: @NPehrsson, Did you end up going with this?

Comment: @Terry, we builded our own

Comment: The "Caution" statement in the documentation for the constructor of this class really gives me pause. It's long, recommends global variables, and says vaguely unsettling things about application lifecycle. It starts with a riddle: "Do not create MemoryCache instances unless it is required." Hmm... this doesn't seem like the lightweight "ConcurrentDictionary that expires entries" that I'm looking for. Interested in others' experiences. (ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.memorycache.aspx)

Comment: @pettys Ha! I came across a need for caching recently and was also scared off by the fine-print. At it's core, there's some very dark-magic going on in MemoryCache. How does it know when to shed items when it approaches memory limits? How is that measured? Supposing your cached items refer to some common state... are they included in the measurements? In the end I opted for writing my own implementation that uses a combination of SortedList and Dictionary to do its bidding, but had to fall back on locking over concurrent collections to keep everything synchronized.

Comment: I wouldn't trust MemoryCache to always retain entries until they expire, a cache can and should empty items if it deems itself too full. So no good if you need to guarantee no false "misses" (i.e. not just a cache)

Answer (score 5):

> **Disclaimer**: I'm one of the contributors of the OSS package I mention below!

The downsides of `MemoryCache` are:

- Not generic (causes boxing/unboxing for primitively typed keys and values)
- Comes with bloat (OS performance counters, heuristic and black magic to decide when to evict non-expired items under "memory pressure" etc)
- Uses string keys only (allocates every time you search)
- Exhausts memory quickly when scanning keys

These are the exact reasons we wrote [FastCache](https://github.com/jitbit/FastCache) with 10x faster writes, 6x faster reads, etc. It's basically just that - an expiring `ConcurrentDictionary`.