# Is my C# implementation of a dictionary with item expiration safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm in my early days of working with C# and threading and I'm in need of a data structure that can store key-value pairs like a dictionary, but after a certain time after being added I want the values to "expire", or get removed from the dictionary.

I have come up with an implementation that seems to work, but I was wondering if there might be any problems to it when used in a multi threaded environment.

1. Are there any direct issues with my current implementation?
2. As all usage of the dictionary is protected by the semaphore, is this implementation to be considered thread-safe out of the box?

```
public class TokenCache<TKey, TValue>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    where TValue : class
{
    private readonly TimeSpan expirationTime;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> cache;

    public TokenCache(TimeSpan expirationTime)
    {
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
        this.semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        this.cache = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.semaphore.Wait();

        try
        {
            this.cache[key] = value;

            Task
                .Run(() => Thread.Sleep(this.expirationTime))
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    this.Remove(key);
                });
        }
        finally
        {
            this.semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public void Remove(TKey key)
    {
        this.semaphore.Wait();

        try
        {
            this.cache.Remove(key);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public TValue GetValueOrDefault(TKey key)
    {
        this.semaphore.Wait();

        try
        {
            if (this.cache.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be reinventing the wheel. Have you considered using [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes I looked at MemoryCache, but I did not understand how to use it if my key is anything else than a string... In my case it's a struct. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you include an example of how you use the `TokenCache<TKey, TValue>` class? The class itself might be thread-safe but the usage might not be, because of race conditions. So we need to see the usage too.

Comment: @Resnick Unfortunately MemoryCache does need a string key.

Comment: As a side note, is there any particular reason that you prefer to synchronize the code with a cumbersome `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)`, instead of the convenient [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement?

Comment: I don't think Thread.Sleep is a good idea. Better use Task.Delay IMHO

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I don't have the real usage implemented yet. But in what scenario would I have problems with race conditions for this implementation?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Makes it cleaner for sure, thanks :) Any particular reason to why it's better?

Comment: Is it really important to actively remove the expired item from the cache or you just want to make sure that when you access an already expired item, it gets updated? If the latter, then you can use my [ThreadSafeCacheFactory](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Collections_ThreadSafeCacheFactory.htm). When configured for expiring items it will use a [`Cache<TKey, TValue>`](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#cachetkey-tvalue) internally. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTbCPV) is a live demo.

Comment: For working (or "working", where you believe it probably works) code that you're seeking to improve, the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site is probably a better fit.

Comment: Here is an example of a race condition: Two threads call the `TokenCache.GetValueOrDefault` which returns `null`. Both threads start a high latency operation that retrieves the value, and then both call the `TokenCache.Add` method, at slightly different times. Now you have two timers that will try to evict the same key at different times. After the key is evicted by the first timer, the second timer will be still active. In the meantime another thread might add again the same key, which will be unexpectedly removed shortly after by the phantom timer.

Comment: Don't do this. There are plenty of existing cache libraries. Use an exciting one instead.

Comment: You could take a look at [this](https://github.com/jitbit/FastCache/blob/main/FastCache/FastCache.cs) piece of code (`FastCache<TKey, TValue>` class by [Alex from Jitbit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73785116/11178549)), for ideas about how to implement correctly a `ConcurrentDictionary` with expiring keys. That implementation is not perfect, but it's way better than your `TokenCache<TKey, TValue>` class.

Answer (score 2):

Problems I see in no particular order (there might be more though):

### Task.Run

`Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(...))` is a very bad idea. The `ThreadPool`, which contains the threads that run `Task`s has a limited amount of threads (it can grow, but it grows very slowly!!) and by calling `Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(...))` instead of `Task.Delay(...)` you're wasting a `ThreadPool` thread for the duration of the wait. `Task.Delay(...)` doesn't use up a thread.

### Wrong Item Expiration

Another problem is your `Add` method. Think about the following:

- You create an instance of `TokenCache`, for example via `new TokenCache<int, string>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))`
- You call `Add(10, "ten")`
- After 50 seconds, you call `Remove(10)`
- After 5 more seconds, you call `Add(10, "The Number 10");`
- Because of the way you've written your `Add` method, you're now going to remove the value `"The Number 10"` after only 5 seconds

### Pointless Semaphore

Also, I don't really see the point of using a `SemaphoreSlim`. In this scenario you could just use the `lock` keyword on something like `private readonly object locker = new();`